# Navigation drawer not displaying up icon when opened

Tags: navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Using architecture navigation component I am able to link my toolbar to the navigation drawer using this code:

```
    val appbarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.landing_dest), drawer_root)
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appbarConfiguration)
```

The problem is that when opening the navigation drawer the toolbar icon does not transition to the Up icon that once pressed with close the drawer.

Using navigation component how can I get the Up arrow in the toolbar when navigation drawer is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this this the material way https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122272983.

Solution really is to manage back stack on your own if you want the up button to show when the menu is opened.